# Двойное событие onsubmit

Tags: javascript, метрики, форма

Нужно Яндекс.Метрикой фиксировать успешные отправки заявки через форму.

Варианты подключения

**Установка на форму**

```
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;">
```

**Установка на кнопку**

```
    <form action="">
        <input type="button" onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;" value="Заказать" />
    </form>
```

При установке на кнопку фиксируется не отправка заявки, а любое нажатие кнопки Отправить, даже если отправка не совершилась, а просто возникло окно о том, что что-то не заполнено.

**Сама форма**

```
<form id="mailform_id" name="mailform_id" onsubmit="check_mailform_id('id'); return false;">
```

При отправке вызывается функция проверки введенных данных `check_mailform_id('id')`
Конец функции проверки:

```
if(error==false){
    var MyForm=document.getElementById('mailform_'+id);
    MyForm.submit();
}
```

Подскажите, как поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. Самый простой и корявый:

```
<form id="mailform_id" name="mailform_id" onsubmit="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); check_mailform_id('id'); return false;">
```

Или можно повесить на форму `.submit()` и там вызвать функции, которые вам надо.

Comment: Спасибо. 
Чем плох этот способ?

Comment: Чище и красивее, когда скрипты вынесены из html.

Comment: можно повесить на форму .submit() и там вызвать функции которые вам надо
Если не сложно, расскажите чуть подробнее?

Comment: $(document).ready(
 function(){
  $("form").submit(function() {
             alert('Первое событие');
                    yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER')
                    return check_mailform_id('id'); // true или false
  })
 }
);